# UIImageView subclass for circle icon in IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder

I need to create a UIImageView subclass that cuts an image to a circle shape, and draws a border.
I set the image view and image in a storyboard.

The `initWithCoder` method of my subclass is called, but other methods, such as `drawRect:` and `setImage:` are not called (I set breakpoints in every method). And the image that appears is not cropped.

Why are drawRect: and setImage: are not called?

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't use `imageView.layer`?
for example:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.height/2.0f; // for circle shape
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0; 
imageView.layer.borderColor;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

P.S. I'm sorry that i write here, small reputation...

Comment: Yep, ok. It works, thanks, but why those methods are not called when I create my view from interface builder?

Comment: Because, drawRect it's subclass of UIView, you can modify in this method any object, but in subclass of UIView

Comment: UIImageView is subclass of UIView, and my class is subclass of UIImageView ... so my class is inheritor of UIView